# wavwrite outputting file with no sound

Tags: matlab, audio, filtering, wav

I'm simply trying to output 3 sound files (.wav) using `wavwrite`. The data I am using in MATLAB plays the sound fine using `soundsc`, but for some reason 2 out of the 3 sound files do not have any sound.

```
[data,Fs] = wavread('prj1.wav'); %Data file I read in
...%filtering with cascaded FIR filter

dataFiltered = filter(Hd,data); %applying filter to data
soundsc(dataFiltered,Fs) %plays perfectly
pause(6)
wavwrite(dataFiltered,Fs,'FIR_Cascade_Signal.wav'); %writes out perfectly, can play back fine.
```

My problem arises after this:

```
...%Filter with different method, simple IIR filter if curious

dataFiltered2 = filter(Gd,data); %applying second type of filter
soundsc(dataFiltered2,Fs) %plays back fine, loud and clear
pause(6)
```

Plays the sound perfectly

```
wavwrite(dataFiltered2,Fs,'IIR_Cascade_Signal.wav');%Outputted file has NO SOUND
```

writes out a sound file, but can't hear anything

```
...%Filtering with notch filter. This uses dataFiltered2 as the first stage, and then filters out a 30Hz harmonic with the Notch filter

Yfilt_stage2 = filter(B,a,dataFiltered2);
soundsc(Yfilt_stage2,Fs);  %Plays loud and clear, can hear everything
wavwrite(Yfilt_stage2,Fs,'Notch_Filtered_Signal.wav');%Again, no sound in output file
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you listen to it with `sound` instead of `soundsc`? Also, `wavwrite` will be removed in a future release, perhaps you could consider using `audiowrite` instead.

Comment: It sounds like `soundsc`. I also realize that `audiowrite` will replace `wavewrite`. Right now, the functions are the same and both do not write out any sound. I think it may just be a problem with my computer and I'm looking into it.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a minimalist example where we could reproduce the problem? Perhaps using some example WAV files and filters. Also, are you able to plot the signals through each stage and isolate the problem at `wavwrite`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with my computer itself. I tried my code on another computer and it worked fine.